# angularjs ngRoute dont redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="routeApp">
<head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controlles.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>route mapping application</title>
</head>

<body>
    salut

    <div ng-view></div>
    <br>

    <nav>
        <a href="#/home">Page d'accueil</a>
        <a href="#/contact">Page de contact</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and the controllers:

```
'use strict'

/**
 * Déclaration de l'application routeApp
 */
var routeApp = angular.module('routeApp', [
    // Dépendances du "module"
    'ngRoute'
]);

routeApp.config(['$routeProvider',

    function($routeProvider) {
        //systeme de routage

        console.log('rederction');

        $routeProvider.when('/home',{templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'})
                      .when ('/contact/',{templateUrl: 'views/contact.html', controller: 'contactCtrl'})
                      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    }
]);

// Contrôleur de la page d'accueil
routeApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Bienvenue sur la page d'accueil";
    }
]);

// Contrôleur de la page de contact
routeApp.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Laissez-nous un message sur la page de contact !";
    }
]);
```

and the home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controlles.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home </title>
</head>

<body>
    template home : {{message}}
    {{2+2}}
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I test that in Internet Explorer, I get an access denied error, and in Google Chrome I receive the following

```
Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/mehdi/PhpstormProjects/mapping/views/home.html'.
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: can't run ajax application using local file ... needs to be run from server due to browser security. Easy to set up a localhost server on your computer

Comment: Your home template shouldn't include head and angular script stuffs, as it will be injected in the `<div ng-view>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include *angular-route.js* as the routing is in a separate module.
You want to avoid yourself errors by using the *same* version of *angular-route.js* and *angular.js*, in your example **1.3.14**

Be sure to have in your homepage :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Second, be aware that your template *home.html* will be injected in the `<div ng-view>` of your application homepage, that you probably named *index.html*. So you have to remove the doctype, all the `<head>` tag, and keep only the body content wrapped in a tag. Like this :

- *home.html*

  ```
  <div>
      template home : {{message}}
      {{2+2}}
  </div>
  ```

Also, as charlietfl stated, you will need to run your app through a web server, as the templates are fetched by XHR requests

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your index.html from a web server instead of a file directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access the resources through the file system rather than through an HTTP server.

If you aren't planning to use a backend for the time being, a quick way to get you going is to install a [node static server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-server) and start serving from your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this code on a web server. Checkout Apache Tomcat - it is free and easy to use. I would suggest that you make these changes:

On your main html page the nav links should look like this (remove the forward slashes):

```
<nav>
    <a href="#home">Page d'accueil</a>
    <a href="#contact">Page de contact</a>
</nav>
```

The home.html and contact.html pages should look like this:

```
<div>
    template home : {{message}}
    {{2+2}}
</div>
```

Your route provider should look like this (remove the forward slash following contact) :

```
  $routeProvider.when('/home',{templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                                     controller: 'homeCtrl'})
                      .when ('/contact',{templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
                                         controller: 'contactCtrl'})
                      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'}
        );
```